# Matlab Expression

Tags: matlab, expression

```
P0 = 1000

r = 0.08


t = 1:30

P = P0 exp(r*t)
```

I'm getting an error Unexpected MATLAB expression, please help.

Comment: Do you want 'P = P0 * exp(r*t)'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write:

```
P = P0*exp(r*t)
```

Comment: Cheers to you and the rest!